# How to remove first letter and last letter of a string of unknown length by excluding string characters?

Tags: python, string, character

To write a program that reads word and prints length of a word excluding the first and last character.

**Sample:** `input:Blockchain.`
**Output:**`8(by excluding first and last char of string.)`

I tried getting the first letter of string and got it but unable to get it's last letter since string  is of unknown length.

Comment: by slicing .. `string[1:-1]`

Comment: If you want the length of a string excluding its first and last characters then just print the length minus 2. You will need to allow for strings with fewer than 2 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just minus 2 from the actual length of the string.

```
print(len(string)-2)
```

If your string has characters less than 2 then the above one returns the negative length.

Then use this one.

```
length = max(len(string) - 2, 0)
print(length)
# This will convert negative numbers to 0. Because 0 is greater than negative numbers.
```

Or if you want the string without the first and last character.

```
print(string[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

By slicing you can achieve your desired output..!

Example:-

```
word=input("Enter the word: ")
print("Word after slicing: "+word[1:-1]+" Length of word: "+str(len(word[1:-1])))
```

**Output:-**

```
Enter the word: Blockchain
Word after slicing: lockchai Length of word: 8
```

Answer (score -1):

With input = 'blockchain', you can use input[-1]